# Inherited variables does not work

Tags: php

i have probably a really easy problem, but i dont know how to fix it now. Maybe i just forgot something, but i need your help.

I have model:

```
    <?php

class Model
{
  protected $storage;
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->storage = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/mvc/images/";
    if(!file_exists($this->storage))
    {
      mkdir($this->storage, 0777);
    }
  }
  public function storageHandler()
  {   
    if(count(glob($this->storage."/*")) === 0)
      {
      echo "Žiadne kategórie";
      }
    else
    {  
      $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($this->storage);
      return $iterator;
    }
  }

}

?>
```

And model Category, which is inherited from Model.

```
    <?php
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/mvc/model/Model.php");
  class Category extends Model
  {
  private $photos_count;
   public function __construct($data)
    {
        if(isset($data))
        {
          $gallery_path = $this->storage . $data;
          if(!file_exists($this->$storage .$data))
          {
          mkdir($tihs->storage . $data, 0700);
          header("Location: /mvc/" );
          }
          else
          {
          echo "Kategória už existuje.";
          }
        }
    }


  }

?>
```

I would love to use $storage variable from Model in my Category class. How should I do that? I know some way, but it's not gonna be the best one. Is there any solution that will make this good way?

Comment: Other than the typo, what's wrong with the way you're doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

besides Ray's answer you need you use `parent::__construct()` in your category class like so

```
class Category extends Model
  {
  private $photos_count;
   public function __construct($data)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //rest of the code
```

Answer (score 2):

The protected property $storage is available to your child class, but `$this` is spelt wrong in your examp:

```
   mkdir($tihs->storage . $data, 0700);
```

It should be:

```
  $this->storage ...
```

Also, as notedby mamdouh, you need to call the parent constructor from the child to initialize:

```
public function __construct($data)
{
    parent::_construct();
     ...rest of code...
```